# How can I create scroll effect like Waven Website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a scroll effect like Waven Website, using vanilla html, css and javascript, that when you scroll, the whole page goes down, but i don't want to use just CSS like:

```
  section{ 
   scroll-snap-align: start; 
  }
```

```
  .container{
   scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
   overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

Because when I use this method, the page scroll a little and after a second scroll the whole section, I want some method when you scroll, the page goes instantly down.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, please see snippet below or [working codepen](https://codepen.io/lucasroquilly/pen/dydjXGM) .

```js
// original example (without scroll with mouse) : 
// https://codepen.io/VeronQ/pen/MVzNOg

function scroll(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // iterate through all inputs
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="item"]')
  for(var i = 0;i < inputs.length;i++){
    if(inputs[i].checked){
      //check which input is checked and check next one or previous one according to the event.deltaY (scroll up or down)
      if(event.deltaY>0 && i!=inputs.length-1)
        inputs[i+1].checked = true
      else if(event.deltaY<0 && i!=0)
        inputs[i-1].checked = true
      break;
    }
  }
}
// attach scroll function to onwheel event
document.onwheel = scroll;
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Carter+One);
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]#section1:checked ~ nav label[for=section1] {
  background-color: white;
}

input[type=radio]#section1:checked ~ section:nth-of-type(1) {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

input[type=radio]#section1:checked ~ .cover {
  background-color: #f8b195;
}

input[type=radio]#section2:checked ~ nav label[for=section2] {
  background-color: white;
}

input[type=radio]#section2:checked ~ section:nth-of-type(2) {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

input[type=radio]#section2:checked ~ .cover {
  background-color: #c06c85;
}

input[type=radio]#section3:checked ~ nav label[for=section3] {
  background-color: white;
}

input[type=radio]#section3:checked ~ section:nth-of-type(3) {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

input[type=radio]#section3:checked ~ .cover {
  background-color: #6c5c7c;
}

input[type=radio]#section4:checked ~ nav label[for=section4] {
  background-color: white;
}

input[type=radio]#section4:checked ~ section:nth-of-type(4) {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

input[type=radio]#section4:checked ~ .cover {
  background-color: #345d7e;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.nav__item {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  display: block;
  margin: 12px auto;
  border: solid 2px white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav__item:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #f8b195;
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #c06c85;
}

section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #6c5c7c;
}

section:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: #345d7e;
}

.cover {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  font: 100% "Carter One", cursive;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Inputs-->
<input type="radio" name="item" checked="checked" id="section1"/>
<input type="radio" name="item" id="section2"/>
<input type="radio" name="item" id="section3"/>
<input type="radio" name="item" id="section4"/>
<!-- Navigation-->
<nav class="nav">
  <label class="nav__item" for="section1"></label>
  <label class="nav__item" for="section2"></label>
  <label class="nav__item" for="section3"></label>
  <label class="nav__item" for="section4"></label>
</nav>
<!-- Sections-->
<section>
  <h1>One Page</h1>
</section>
<section>
  <h1>Pure CSS</h1>
</section>
<section>
  <h1>Full Screen</h1>
</section>
<section>
  <h1>@Ver_Qn</h1>
</section>
<!-- Fix the white space when scrolling two sections at the time-->
<div class="cover"></div>
```